# EasyPHP MySQL Script Speed

Tags: mysql, easyphp

I am using EasyPHP 12.1 with MySQL on an old Windows XP system.  I have a SQL script (script.sql) with < 10 table creations and > 200,000 INSERT INTO statements.  The script is structured like this:

```
SET autocommit = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
USE myDatabase;
...
COMMIT;
```

Where ... is the body of the script, most of which are inserts.

I'm running this with mysql -uuser -ppassword < script.sql.

When I do this, it takes well over an hour to insert ~ 1/3 of the records.  This can't be right, so I must be doing something wrong -- but what?  Can you see any problems with this script?  Are there any known bugs or performance issues with this stack?

Comment: Lacking information. If you're using MyISAM as database engine, I'm frankly not surprised at the speed for 200k append operations...

Comment: I have no idea what engine is used; I just downloaded EasyPHP 12.1 and did not customize it from there.  Is there a faster way to populate a table?

Comment: There isn't. Also, the DB engine is table-specific. Check your CREATE TABLE statements, you should find an ENGINE=something flag. If it's MyISAM, I'm frankly not surprised at the speed. If it's InnoDB, I'm frankly not surprised either if it's an old machine you're running on.

Comment: I wasn't specifying an engine.  I changed that to ENGINE=MEMORY and it ran in about a minute, if not less!!!!!!!!!!!  Thank you very much.

Comment: I'll add a detailed answer, there's one thing that needs to be said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one thing that did not transpire in the comments. **A storage engine affects where the data is stored**. This also affects how it is stored, which leads to MyISAM being slower than innoDB on INSERT (due to myISAM requiring a full index re-write on every insertion).

If you are using the MEMORY engine, consider changing. MEMORY is good for temporary tables - the moment you shut down your server, you'll lose the contents of the tables. MEMORY should **NEVER** be used for permanent tables.

Consider InnoDB, MyISAM, or ARCHIVE if your data is not indexed. This will create significantly higher first-creation times (due to the fact that, unlike MEMORY, both MyISAM, INNODB and ARCHIVE have to write to disk and regenerate indices), but it'll at least mean that your tables will not miraculously disappear the moment you shut the server down.

I'd strongly recommend reading up on the various storage engines, as it is pretty crucial in most cases. There are some very, very cool features in them, too.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  Unfortunately, if the write times of any other engines are on the order of what I experienced, we'll simply abandon an RDBMS.  Anything over 5 full minutes is a non-starter for us, and even 5 full minutes is pushing it, when it takes less than 5 seconds for the proprietary data format this came from :(

Comment: Do you need the data to be persistent and resistant to server faults? If so, you don't really have a choice. I think you had MyISAM by default, though. Set ENGINE=InnoDB and tell me if you've got anything better. If your data is read-only, try ENGINE=ARCHIVE as well.

Comment: I tried InnoDB, but after 7 minutes of processing, I aborted it.  The data is read-only, so I tried ENGINE=ARCHIVE, but that caused table creation to fail with errno: -1.

Comment: I have a question. Why do you need to have it load so often? If you have a central server, consider replication.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  I'm just trying to populate the database.  On a regular basis, the database will be updated with new data sets -- all read only.  The data will be built from elsewhere, and will be remotely "uploaded" into the database by people with limited access rights.

Comment: Okay. If you're doing this, rather than dumping the DB and recreating everything, consider only changing what was actually changed. It'll result in a significantly quicker load time and will therefore not limit you to memory-only storage engines. You can either PARTITION your table or build a homebrewed replication-esque system to do this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19715/discussion-between-user1161318-and-user1800246)

Comment: Ok, it looks like it used a different default engine even though the documentation said it should be MyISAM.  I just explicitly set ENGINE=MyISAM and it did the insertions in < 1 minute. I'm going to test the other engines just to get a performance profile, but MyISAM is definitely acceptable!  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: That's odd. Can you run the insertions the long way and explicitely look at the engine used by the tables in the end? Looks like some extremely odd behaviour.